# There's any workaround for testing components with `Vue.extend` and vue-i18n?

Tags: javascript, vuejs2, karma-mocha, vue-i18n

When we started our project, we didn't use vue-i18n, but we are having some problems with this plugin, it is throwing some warnings on our karma+mocha tests, so I found out this issue on github related to Vue.extend method:

https://github.com/kazupon/vue-i18n/issues/200

Warning example: `WARN: '[vue-i18n] Cannot translate the value of keypath 'input.required'. Use the value of keypath as default.'`

As we already have a lot of tests using this pattern: https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/unit-testing.html#Writing-Testable-Components

I'm wondering, is there any workaround for properly testing components using Vue.extend and vue-i18n?

Comment: any news on this one?

Answer (score 0):

The default locale is "en-US", so if the i18n messages in your component have "en-US", there will be no warning. Otherwise, you can set the locale to "en" before the test cases by using **childComp.i18n.locale = "en"**. I am still looking for a nicer way to dismiss the warnings.

Comment: I actually did that, but the console keeps throwing warnings, so I raised the log level on karma/chrome so it doesn't flood the console. The tests passes because it can compare the throw back words (e.g 'config.email'). But thanks for the answer, I'll try to make more tests doing that and see the behaviour :)